# Variable functions as a list but isn't technically a list? [Python]

Tags: python

I'm pulling a list from a dictionary like so:

```
d={foo:[1,2,3]}
thelist=d[foo]
```

I'm able to get items from indexes of thelist but not like this:

```
for i in thelist:
    print thelist[i]
```

I get an error saying the "list index is out of range"

Additionally, when I run

```
thelist is list
```

it returns False

whats going on here

Comment: `is` is the identity operator. For example `a = []; a is a` returns `True`. `for i in lst` iterates on values, not on indexes. (`1, 2, 3`, not `0, 1, 2`)

Answer (score 3):

the list index out of range is because `thelist[3]` is not an allowed thing to call.

the `for` loop is trying to print `thelist[i]` for each `i` in `thelist`.  In this case `thelist` has `1`, `2`, and `3`.  So it's trying to print `thelist[1]` (which is 2), `thelist[2]` (which is 3), and then `thelist[3]` which is undefined.

A bit more detail:

```
thelist = ['puppy', 1, 'dog']
for i in thelist:
    print i
```

gives

> puppy
>
> 1
>
> dog

as for `thelist is list`, instead try `type(thelist)`.  The type of `thelist` is `list`.  So testing whether `thelist` *is* `list` (that is it is the class of things which we call list) rather than is a `list` (that is it is an example of the list class) will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interate over a list using indices, than you should do as follows:

```
for i,v in enumerate(thelist):
    print(thelist[i])
```

Or alternatively:

```
for i in range(len(thelist)):
    print(thelist[i])
```

Comment: even better: `for v in thelist:  print v`

Comment: @Joel You provided this answer, so why should I copy it. I provide alternative answer.

Comment: I think it would be better to have the three versions in the same place, rather than 2 and expect OP to notice the third in my answer - might get skipped over since my answer might be "too long".  Anyways, no hopefully no offense caused.

Answer (score 0):

in python the default indexing strart from `0` and ends to its lenght-1

so thelist=d[foo] ie `[1,2,3]` will have index `0,1,2`

```
for i in thelist:     # here i the element of list not index
    print thelist[i]


for i in range(len(thelist)):   # here i the index of list
    print thelist[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for l1 in thelist:
   print l1
```

you get:

```
1
2
3
```

in your code you're trying to access list using the list elements as index. Instead, to iterate over list' indexes, you should use `range(len(theList))`(from `0` to `len(theList) -1`) or `reversed(range(len(theList))` (from `len(theList) -1` to `0`).

to check if a variable is a list use `types`

```
import types
x = [1,2,3]
if type(x) is types.ListType:
    print 'x is a list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you go through the for loop, i is set to one of the items in the list.

You'll also want to use the type() function to compare the types of thelist and a list (really []).

```
d={'foo':[1,2,3]}
thelist = d['foo']
for i in thelist:
    print i

print type(thelist)
print type(thelist) is type([])
```

returns

```
1
2
3
<type 'list'>
True
```